# Generar contraseña con salteado usando algoritmo SHA512 en java

Tags: java, android, hash, sha512

Tengo un metodo para crear la contraseña en PHP y lo quiero implementar con java (android)
este es el codigo PHP

```
$pw ="pa$$w0rd";
$digest = "";
$salt ="1muzhbg7x4w00k8sk8ocw8gsk40sw8g"; 
$salted = $pw.'{'.$salt.'}';


 for ($i = 1; $i<= 5000; $i++)
{
   $digest = hash("sha512", $digest . $salted, true);
}
print $digest. "\n";
print base64_encode($digest). "\n";
?>
```

Busco su equivalente en java

Comment: No es buena idea hacer una pregunta "quiero hacer X y no sé, alguien lo hace por mí?". Haz uso de la documentación y de los ejemplos que seguro hay disponibles. Una vez tengas código en Java con el que tengas líos, puedes venir, traer los errores y el código, que seguro te vamos a ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

aqui te dejo la clase que cree para encriptar mis contraseñas, puedes usar cualquiera de los algoritmos de encriptación declarados como constantes, basta implementar el metodo getStringMessageDigest pasandole la cadena a encriptar y el algoritmo con el cual deseamos encriptarlo y te retornará la cadena encriptada.

```
//algoritmos
public static String MD2 = "MD2";
public static String MD5 = "MD5";
public static String SHA1 = "SHA-1";
public static String SHA256 = "SHA-256";
public static String SHA384 = "SHA-384";
public static String SHA512 = "SHA-512";

/**
 * *
 * Convierte un arreglo de bytes a String usando valores hexadecimales
 *
 * @param digest arreglo de bytes a convertir
 * @return String creado a partir de <code>digest</code>
 */
private static String toHexadecimal(byte[] digest) {
    String hash = "";
    for (byte aux : digest) {
        int b = aux & 0xff;
        if (Integer.toHexString(b).length() == 1) {
            hash += "0";
        }
        hash += Integer.toHexString(b);
    }
    return hash;
}

/**
 * *
 * Encripta un mensaje de texto mediante algoritmo de resumen de mensaje.
 *
 * @param message texto a encriptar
 * @param algorithm algoritmo de encriptacion, puede ser: MD2, MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-384, SHA-512
 * @return mensaje encriptado
 */
public static String getStringMessageDigest(String message, String algorithm) {
    byte[] digest = null;
    byte[] buffer = message.getBytes();
    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
        messageDigest.reset();
        messageDigest.update(buffer);
        digest = messageDigest.digest();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No se encontró el algoritmo de cifrado", ex);
    }
    return toHexadecimal(digest);
}
```

slds.